# Where is the object browser in visual studio C# 2010 express edition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, object

I am not sure that this is the right place to ask this, but because all here are programmers, maybe someone could help me.

I always used 2008 express, I decided to try the 2010 version today. The problem now is that I need to check something in the object browser, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to change the settings to expert settings to find it. The object explorer is hidden in basic settings.

[EDIT]
To change them you need to go to Tools > Settings.

Answer (score 7):

ctrl+Alt+j?!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean Object *Browser*?

`View -> Other Windows -> Object Browser`.

Or, `View -> Other Windows -> Database Explorer` (if you meant something like Object Explorer / Server Explorer).

The shortcuts are `Ctrl + W, J` and `Ctrl + W, L`, respectively.

Comment: Aaron is correct in that it doesn't show up in view, or other windows, if vs is in basic settings (which it is set to by default - this is particular true, if you're using express versions, or platform specific versions: like 'vs for desktop', 'vs for web').