# How can I find exception names (in intellisense) availible to throw in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, exception, intellisense

One thing I find very frustrating with C# is when I find some issue and I want to throw a **meaningful** exception. I find it very difficult to find those exceptions in intellisense.  There is no Exception namespace, so I cant list all exceptions via intellisense without digging around looking for the exception.

I am **not** looking to create my own exceptions, I am only trying to see if there are any other options than googling an exception to find its namespace so I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse the entire Exception Class Tree in object Browser. Look for System.Exception and then click derived types. not 100% sure if all of them are there but the most of them are there for sure.
System.Exception -> Derived types (also in the root of the System.Excecption tree)

Comment: i did read the question, the man wants to know the available excecptions built in .NET, am i wrong?

Comment: If you use Express, this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950678/where-is-the-object-browser-in-visual-studio-c-sharp-2010-express-edition  (Shows how to turn on the Object Browser).

Comment: the default hotkeys for the object browser are ctrl + w, j .

Comment: in this case you can use a third party tool like .net reflector or some free equivalent of this tool .

Comment: Doing a search in the object browser for exception is a decent solution in VS2008.

Answer (score 6):

For the most part, this is bad practise.  There are a small handful of exceptions that you should reuse (InvalidOperation, NullReference, ArgumentException, a few others).  But you should not, for example, throw `SqlException` yourself - because you don't know what the framework might do with it.

Creating your own exception hierarchy adds meaning to your application at times of error.  Reusing exceptions that have already-understood meanings leads to confusion - *loss* of meaning.

Comment: This is a great point, however, I dont write the coding standard and I do have to follow the practices in place.

Comment: @Jake1164 Which coding standards?

Comment: What are those standards?  If they encourage you to write unmaintainable code, can you not suggest a change?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some exceptions in the MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5tckx.aspx). 
In general, these are the exceptions you'll ever tend to throw, and in many cases, you'll derive your own exceptions from these exceptions. However, a single method throwing too many different exceptions is generally frowned upon.
Also, recall the [`<exception>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1htk11d.aspx) xml documentation tag. Using this tag goes a long way towards enlightening users which exceptions your method throws, and when. It's probably more important, in terms of clarity, than throwing exceptions of specific classes.